# compare sample data and generated data

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, hypothesis-test

We have sample data, we managed to determine the distribution type that it follows (Generalized Extreme Value) and its parameters (K,Sigma,Mu)

And we generated n samples (10000) from the same distribution with the same parameters and in the same range (between 23.1 and 105.64)

```
pd_gev = makedist('GeneralizedExtremeValue','k',1.2381,'sigma',11.2881,'mu',30.8293);
t = truncate(pd_gev,23.1,105.64);
r = random(t,10000,1);
```

How to make sure that the generated data follows the given distribution of the sample?

Note:(comparing mu, sigma, mean and standard deviation gives very different numbers)

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing

Comment: how can we generate random number using given distribution type and the mean and standard deviation of the sample data??

Comment: Try a [q-q plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q–Q_plot).